# Обозначение неиспользуемых параметров [[maybe_unused]]

Tags: c++, c++17

В процессе переопределения виртуальных методов, и в случае неиспользования отдельных параметров, и дабы избежать предупреждений компилятора, можно опускать имена параметров. Например:

```
bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray&, 
                             void *message,
                             long *)
```

Но, начиная с `С++17` появились атрибуты, один из которых `[[maybe_unused]]`. Что позволяет переписать код выше так:

```
bool MainWindow::nativeEvent([[maybe_unused]] const QByteArray& eventType, 
                             void *message,
                             [[maybe_unused]] long *result)
```

Простой вопрос, что полезного дает это "нововведение"? Пока я вижу, что только разрастается код. Ну, на крайний случай, использование параметра в режиме отладки и неиспользование для релиза.

Comment: Компилятор не будет сыпать предупреждениями о неиспользуемых переменных и функциях.

Comment: Ну это понятно, и в первом и во втором случае. Для этого и делалось. Но почему не обойтись первым вариантом?

Comment: во-первых, данный атрибут применим не только к параметрам функции, во-вторых, у нас остается имя, которое позволяет понять что это за параметр (хотя имя можно закомментировать, это не очень удобно), т.е. сохраняется читаемость, в-третьих, это не всегда возможно или удобно: https://wandbox.org/permlink/otKQwnbCQXV5UDDC

Comment: Ну да, если для отладки - решение годное.

Comment: очень может быть полезно при  переопределении функции  в полиморфных типах. Одному классу может не понадобится  какой то из аргументов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это необходимо при условной компиляции:

```
bool MainWindow::nativeEvent([[maybe_unused]] const QByteArray& eventType, 
                             void *message,
                             [[maybe_unused]] long *result) {
#ifdef HAS_NATIVE_EVENTS
  if(eventType == 0x18) {
    result = eventType[0];
  }
#endif
// ...
}
```

---

<sub>**Дополнено**</sub>

До `[[maybe_unused]]` для того чтобы подавить предупреждение о неиспользуемом параметре/переменной приходилось добавлять хаки из серии `(void)result;` или вообще отключать его.

Частным, но распространённым случаем такого использования является макрос `assert()`, который обычно объявляется как-то вроде:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#  define  assert(expr) ((expr) ? 0 : do_assert_fail())
#else
#  define  assert(expr) (0)
#endif
```

Подробности также можно найти в исходном предложении в комитет по стандартизации С++ [[PDF](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2053.pdf)].

Answer (score 2):

`[maybe_unused]` нужен не для всегда неиспользуемых сущностей, а для возможно неиспользуемых, что следует из названия.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
T foo([[maybe_unused]] T x, [[maybe_unused]] T y) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        return x + y;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)  {
        return x + 42;
    } else {
        return y + 42;
    }
}

int main() {
    foo(1, 2);
    foo(1.f, 2.f);
    foo(1., 2.);
}
```

Если убрать тут атрибуты, то [могут быть предупреждения](https://godbolt.org/z/vbv8sE).

Ещё один частый пример использования — `assert()`, о котором подробнее можно посмотреть в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171020/398802) участника [@Fat-Zer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/277616/fat-zer).

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вы переходили по ссылке?